# Why AWS SNS filtering doesn't ignore unknown message attributes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

The AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html) says that unknown message attributes are ignored by filter policy.

> When Amazon SNS evaluates message attributes against the subscription filter policy, it ignores message attributes that aren't specified in the policy.

However, it seems to be incorrect. Let's say I have such policy:

```
{
    "customer_interests": ["rugby"]
}
```

but message with additional attribute, for example:

```
   "MessageAttributes": {
      "customer_interests": {
         "Type": "String.Array",
         "Value": "[\"rugby\"]"
      },
      "request_id": {
         "Type": "String",
         "Value":"123456"
      }
   }
```

is rejected, even though customer_interests value is correct. I tested it on different params and whenever I add a field that particular policy doesn't except, the **message is rejected**. Can someone explain to me this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

> When Amazon SNS evaluates message attributes against the subscription filter policy, it ignores message attributes that aren't specified in the policy.

I think in the above statement the understanding of ignore is misleading; treat ignore as "rejected".

Check out this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/example-filter-policies.html) which shows when the policy rejects messages

> If any single attribute in this policy doesn't match an attribute assigned to the message, the policy rejects the message.

On the similar grounds, your filtering policy doesn't have `request_id`, which is why it is being rejected.

Comment: thanks, yes it's indeed misleading

Comment: sorry, but I gave it a second thought and I still don't get it. The first example in documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/attribute-key-matching.html shows that such policy (store": [{"exists": true}]) accepts such message ("store": "fans" 
"customer_interests": ["baseball", "basketball"]). Which is the opposite of what you said.

Comment: Here they are using special operator to make store key mandatory, ( if store exist message will be passed) because it is using exist operator., see the below example, which says exists: false here it exclusively care about that store should not be there, then only it will pass the message. This behaviour is due to nature of exist operator.

Comment: but in your question, this behavior will not be achieved due to lack of exist operator, if you want to test with exist operator include `request_id": [{"exists": false}])`, your message will `not ` be rejected